# how to check the string contain AND and OR in search query params in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Hi I need to make our the query from the query string for filter data from the given model,

the Query will be
[http://127.0.0.1:3007/admin/test/testfilter/?q=user:cadmus@test.com AND age:15](http://127.0.0.1:3007/admin/test/testfilter/?q=user:cadmus@test.com%20AND%20age:15),

Need to get result in following format

```py
from django.models import Q
models.objects.filter(Q(user=cadmus@test.com) & Q(age=15))
```

Comment: how to check the string contain AND and OR in  search query params in django admin

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
   query = Q()

   if 'AND' in request.GET['q']:
        query_parts = request.GET['q'].split('AND')
        for part in query_parts:
            query = query & Q(part.split(':')[0]=part.split(':')[1])
            models.objects.filter(query)
   elif 'OR' in request.GET['q']:
        query_parts = request.GET['q'].split('OR')
        ...
   else:
        ...
```